# Installing Windows From Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, installation

So here is my issue. 
I'm looking to install my copy of Windows 7 Home Premium to a Secondary Hard Drive currently installed in my PC.

I have partitioned my 3TB(MBR) into two separate Partitions one for my OS the other for my files etc...

I have my Copy of Windows on a bootable USB. 
My question is :

Why can't I run the install of windows from within windows?
Every time I try, it begins to install , then restarts the PC and tries to continue the install. Once there it tells me it "Cannot install to this, Partition" that's it, that's all it says. I have no mouse or keyboard control at that point and have to shutdown.

All I'm looking to do is setup everything while IN my current install of windows in order to easily backup and move things.

What do I have to do to make this happen?

Comment: Why don't you run your windowes installation from your bootable USB?

Comment: I'm thinking I'm not going to have any choice but too. However I was trying to do install while at the same time organize to save time. So was curious if I could at all make it happen. Install windows and during installation on New HDD Organize files on old HDD and prepare to move them over etc...

Answer (score 1):

NEVER try to install Windows into a non-boot partition, or onto a non-default drive. Recipe for disaster. Either temporarily disconnect SATA1 or else change the BIOS boot order so the empty disk is the first in line. (Better disconnecting as you *know* that will stop access to the wrong disk)

Most computers will boot from USB, but if you cannot, then an alternative would be to get a copy of WinPE from Microsoft and run the install under that. It comes with the AIK kit.

Comment: Much obliged. Thank you for the prompt answer. It was all an experiment to save time and what seems obvious to me now in Futility. :) Thanks again

Comment: Installing Windows as per OP will cause that install to be unusable when the primary drive is removed, since the secondary drive won't have a MBR setup, so it'll be pointless.